# My new job keeps pushing my start date back due to “background check not clearing yet” it’s been three months

Tags: united-states, background-check

I started this new job but they keep pushing my start date back, and every time, call the day before my expected start date to tell me I will get a new project with a later start date until my background clears.

So I have a record and I asked if it’s because of that and they said no, they don’t know, they just know it hasn’t cleared and I can’t start until it does.

So I finally started this past Friday and got an email Saturday saying some may not be able to continue they just let us start anyway waiting on the rest of the background checks. Today, Sunday, I got the call saying I can’t come in tomorrow because of the background not clearing yet, and I will be assigned a new project and start date.

It’s because I’m a convict isn’t it? I don’t u first and how they had me submit all these background checks after hiring me and letting me accept the offers and I even got to start. Is this legal? I did not lie; I am honest on all applications FYI .

Comment: Are you using your real name as your username? If you are, I recommend you ask the mods to change your username. You don't want people to google your full name and find out that you're a convict. Anyway, in which jurisdiction are you in and what type of job are you applying for? The jurisdiction you're in (and the type of job you're applying for) will dictate how the background check is conducted.  If you're in California for instance, this kind of stuff is highly regulated. In the meantime, you should keep on applying to other jobs.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you !

Comment: The job is based out of Arizona and I’m working from home in Virginia. Or. Would be WFH/Remote work for a healthcare agency I googled that as well and apparently no convicts can work in that field could that be why? Will they tell me it’s because of my record?

Comment: You were up-front with them about your criminal record right?  If so, there should be no surprises.  If you were less than fully honest then that may be a bog problem.

Comment: *”… apparently no convicts can work in that field…”* Is that an Arizona or Virginia law/regulation or is it federal? A link to what you found may be useful. I agree with Stephan that regardless of what is going on, you should restart your job hunt.

Comment: Something sounds fishy about this. A background check should normally be turned around fairly quickly. I'm wondering what they mean by "it hasn't cleared yet". Do they mean it hasn't been performed? It hasn't been completed? It has been completed but they don't know what to do with the results? Nothing about this seems normal to me. Did you happen to pay a fee for the privilege of applying for this job?

Comment: I don't know the law in Arizona. But usually, it depends on the type of conviction you had. For instance, if you wrote a bad check, getting a job as a cashier, or in medical billing, or as a CFO, may be problematic. Or if you had a drug-related offense, getting a job as a nurse could be a problem. If you're a convict, I suppose you could be considered a security-risk where it comes to dealing with HIPAA related information as well, I don't know. Could you get your record expunged? Anyway, definitely apply to different types of jobs.

Comment: @joeqwerty, Background checks can be tricky, especially when multiple jurisdictions are involved. It's possible that they found someone with a criminal record, but that for legal reasons, they need to triple-check that it's the same person as the OP before giving out a definitive answer. All of this takes times.

Comment: @Tonia, The next thing you may want to change is your avatar. In this age of reverse-image searches and AI facial recognition, it's possible that your identity could be automatically uncovered by smart search engines.

Comment: @Tonia I have experience with federal contractors.  The federal government is quite picky and arbitrary about who works for it.  Some contractors will hire people to "work on the bench" while the feds clear the new hire.  The new hire has stuff to do and draws a paycheck while the background check completes.  More commonly, contractors make conditional offers.  If you have a conditional offer, you should be actively looking for work.

Comment: @Tonia, Also, you should double-check the laws of the state before you apply in that state. In California for instance, it's much easier for a former convict to find a job in (depending on the type of job they're applying for). https://www.workplacefairness.org/background-checks-state-law

Comment: Thank you everyone. 
1 yes I am always upfront and honest on my applications. 
2- unfortunately I have a violent offense and am working on expungement. I’m thinking this is the reason I noticed drug related and non violent offense have more leeway in almost everything. 
3 it’s been three months they hired me but I have not started officially until last Friday. I filled out my tax forms and all and today they called and said I will not be able to move forward

Comment: I will change my avatar. Thank you. 
So i will continue to job hunt in the mean time I’m studying for my real estate license I’m hoping I’ll make it through until I graduate.

Comment: And honestly I didn’t know it was based in Arizona until I had the interviews. I was on indeed and applied wherever I felt capable. I suppose I should be more aware and slow down and pay attention. I’ve gotten jobs in the past where despite what I was led to believe, I was hired so I guess I was just shooting my shot.

Comment: Have you tried asking the company what specific problem they are having with the background check? It might be something as trivial as not being able to contact someone, or that person not responding to emails or letters. You may be able to help by providing alternative details or notifying someone to look out for a request for a reference. (If they had genuinely decided not to hire, I'd expect them to tell you that, even if they don't provide a proper reason, rather than what they're doing - it sounds like they want to employ you but need to complete their processes.)

Comment: @Tonia, was this an white collar offense such that trust could be an issue especially in working with HIPPA data or possibly caring for patients / vulnerable folks?

Comment: @StuartF The hiring company might not know what the problem with the background check is. I think background checks are typically conducted by third-party companies, and that company might not be willing to give any information until the check is completed. (It does seem odd that the check is taking that long rather than coming back with a "no".)

Comment: It's really mind boggling that in the US, working contracts aren't actual contracts. In other countries, if someone hires you starting date X, they have to pay you from that day on and if they don't want to put you to work for whatever reason, that is *their* problem. You would simply not get a contract if something is still pending. Wouldn't help you get that specific job, but at least you would have a chance to not quit and still work at the old job and not be left in such a void.

Comment: @stuartf I did ask and all they say is it’s taking longer than expected and they don’t know all they can see is it hasn’t cleared their clients have strict guidelines on it

Comment: @anthony no unfortunately I got into a physical altercation. I have no white collar fraud no financial theft or drug related offenses.

Comment: @keith that’s what I said. A simple no would suffice. I’ve been hired for three months without being able to start until now and then this

Comment: @nvoigt - The contract was conditional, based on the fact, the author would pass the background check.  The author did not pass the background check, the company was willing or it appear, planning to allow the author to work on a conditional basis but it appears they got the results back before that could happen.

Comment: @Donald Yes, "conditional". Where I live, if a signee doesn't actually want to enter a contract under certain conditions, they are to clarify them first and only then sign the contract. Having a clause that is completely intransparant and out of the control of one signee in a contract would probably void that contract alltogether. That is basic contract law here, you can only sign a contract on something where you know the quality and quantity. You cannot contractually agree to unknowns.

Comment: Even in the US, this only happens with working contracts. You would *never* sign a contract that reads "I will pay a sum of money later to be determined by the seller for a TV of a size conditional on the sellers warehouse stocks, delivered to me, maybe on friday or never at all". That is not a contract. A contract is "I will pay 500$ for this specific make and model to be delivered to me between monday and wednesday". No unknowns. Unknowns or conditions not transparent to both parties is not how contracts work.

Comment: @nvoigt - Being hired on the condition of someone passing a background check is a pretty straightforward condition. Your example isn’t realistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more a general answer than a specific one for your case as of course nobody except those performing the checks can tell about that and they'll be under a strict NDA not to.

Security checks take time, sometimes a lot of time depending on the level of the clearance needed and the background of the person being checked.

For example for my clearance, which is minimal (access to some privileged data and secured facilities, and trust to work on software for higher secured areas) the check took 6 weeks. And that was considered to be fast, probably because I'm pretty boring with no criminal record, no relations to people from 'countries of interest', no travel record to such countries, and very few relatives.

For you, with a criminal record containing violent offenses (as per your admission in comments) it would likely take quite a bit longer to get the same clearance (though you may still have got it, not for me to know or say). If you're applying for a position that requires stricter background checks, it will take longer still. If you have a large family, those will have to be checked into (to some degree) as well, taking yet more time.

And if the agency performing the checks has to wait on things like court records, answers from agencies in other jurisdictions or even other countries, etc. etc., add even more time.

It is frustrating, I know, but that's the way it is even for someone who is squeaky clean (which you're not, apparently). E.g. my father would have had to wait longer than me for the same check I underwent because he'd traveled to Colombia once. That'd set off alarm bells about possible connections with drugs cartels (though it'd be easy to verify that one, as he went for business negotiations with government officials there). And they go back a LONG way for such things. 10 years or so where I live, maybe different where you are.

Comment: Just as an example it is taking the FBI upwards of 12-18 months for background checks for a SECRET clearance to be cleared, and that background check is just basic references, when compared to more involved security clearances.  To be clear getting a SECRET clearance involves more than just references, but when compared to actual human interviews for more involved clearances, it's a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2):

The process went through several legal jurisdictions, Virginia and Arizona.  The lawyers may have taken a bit of time to untangle whether or not to apply Ariznona, or Virginia laws (Or federal) laws to see if you could pass a background check.

Most likely it was the Felony that tripped you up.  Some states are more lenient than others, so it may have come down to the more stringent regulations being applied.

FYI, depending on the state, and the nature of the conviction, you may be able to get the conviction expunged from your record.  It's worth investigating the requirements for your state to see if it is possible.

The real problem is that hiring convicted felons carries with it certain liabilities, and even though a company may want to take a risk, their insurance might block them.

The ray of hope here is that you impressed them enough to try to clear it through legal to hire you.  It's frustrating, but try looking for programs that are partnered with companies looking to give felons a second chance.  Some of these businesses are actually owned and run by convicted felons who don't mind giving them the second chance that they got, or was denied to them and they managed to get the business running.

Good luck, it looks like you're really trying to live the good life.

TLDR: Look to have your record expunged, and look for programs that partner with companies that hire convicts.

Comment: Thanks again everyone. 
So here’s an update : I received an email I think was supposed to come with the call I got on Sunday but it was the letter of separation it did not have a reason. The voicemail left on Sunday said I would be removed from this project and not to return to training since the background hasn’t cleared yet. Again and I’d be assigned to a new project with a later start date. Once again. Until my background clears…… I’d assume this email is the attachment to that voicemail I asked about any future projects but In reality I’ll read between the lines

Comment: I’ve got several interviews lined up and I’m confident in my abilities.will be looking into expungement I know in order to overcome the statistics (I’ve pretty much put on myself) comes with struggles and things like this but it’s okay. I was tripped up this time because I’ve gotten clearances through jobs and passed checks before. A previous job I had with a courier and logistics comp I dealt with patient info and healthcare as well and had TSA clearance as well.

Comment: After reading on my own and through the comments I suppose it’s levels to it. I appreciate everyone’s feedback so much. I will continue to move forward. Thank you all also. Can I apply for unemployment now ?

Comment: @Tonia You've got a really good attitude, The kind that opens doors and makes people want to give you a chance,  You own your bad choices and accept that you have to bear the consequences.  That's far more than most people do.  I've got a good feeling about you.  Keep it up!  We all have obstacles to overcome, but a good attitude can carry you through

Comment: well they just called and said that they have another project offer to give my background check time to come back. Do you all suggest I just send them their laptop and equipment back ? Throw the towel in I’m so confused by them. The company is called BroadPath anyone have or know of anything

Comment: @oldlamp thank you. So much.

Comment: @Sonya IT looks like they are trying damn hard to bring you on board.  They are devoting plenty of time, effort and money to do it  That means you impressed the hell out of them.  But also apply elsewhere, in case it doesn't work out.  Keep up the enthusiasm with them, but keep looking and cover all your bets

Comment: Yes it seems that way at first being that in the interview they specifically said they were impressed and offered me a better position and pay than what I applied for. I’m really trying to go with their flow but ya know …. Bills. Lol I just left an interview with Amazon dsp and geez I aced that interview but once he asked about my record I saw disappointment in his eyes.  I’d rather someone say “hey can’t hire you your record is a no no” than “I’ll keep your info and review and get back to you “ if u KNO ur not going to get back to me haha. That’s tactless but I’m not sensitive so

Comment: @Tonia I have a few disabilities, so, I go through similar things.  The laws are worse than useless because they make employers go through the motions with no intent of hiring you.  They waste the employers time and give you false hope.  Better to hear the "no" early on.  If you can target smaller employers, they are usually less rigid.

Comment: @oldLamp yes. It seems maybe this real estate course will be my main lifeline. More eager than ever to complete it now that this has happened. I think I’ll focus on that fully